# Changing the background color of another ViewController's UIView inside a different View Controller inside a Page View Controller

Tags: swift

I was following a YouTube tutorial on how to create a swipe-able PageViewController for an onboarding experience.

[Swift 4: How to create walkthrough screens?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1F_HVMHocdA)

I have everything working but I wanted to tweak the design. Currently the design has two containers. The tutorial shows how to change the design for the top container but not the bottom.

[image: Example Design Picture]

Here is a storyboard overview of the situation

[image: Storyboard overview]

I created an array of colors that change when the user swipes through the page view controller but I want to make the bottom container (white area) also follow this pattern.

In my `WalkthroughPageViewController` i have all of the arrays for the images, title text, sub text, and background colors.

I have the following function

```
func contentViewController(at index: Int) -> WalkthroughContentViewController? {
if index < 0 || index >= pageHeadings.count {
  return nil
}

// Create a new view controller and pass suitable data
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Onboarding", bundle: nil)


if let pageContentViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "WalkthroughContentViewController") as? WalkthroughContentViewController {
  pageContentViewController.imageFile = pageImages[index]
  pageContentViewController.heading = pageHeadings[index]
  pageContentViewController.subHeading = pageSubheadings[index]
  pageContentViewController.backgroundColor = pageBackgroundColorArray[index]
  pageContentViewController.textColor = UIColor(contrastingBlackOrWhiteColorOn: pageBackgroundColorArray[index], isFlat: true)
  pageContentViewController.index = index
  return pageContentViewController
}

return nil
}
```

In my `WalkthroughContentViewController` I have

```
var index = 0
var heading = ""
var headingColor: UIColor?
var subHeading = ""
var subHeadingColor: UIColor?
var imageFile = ""
var backgroundColor: UIColor?
var textColor: UIColor?
```

and in `ViewDidLoad`

```
  headingLabel.numberOfLines = 0
  subHeadingLabel.numberOfLines = 0

  headingLabel.text = heading
  headingLabel.textColor = textColor

  subHeadingLabel.text = subHeading
  subHeadingLabel.textColor = textColor

  contentImageView.image = UIImage(named: imageFile)
  containerView.backgroundColor = backgroundColor
```

**I want to do the same thing to `WalkthroughViewController`** so I can change the background color of that UIView however so far I have not had luck. I have tried adding:

```
if let pageViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "WalkthroughViewController") as? WalkthroughViewController {
  pageViewController.backgroundColor = pageBackgroundColorArray[index]

}
```

as well as the same properties in that VC

What have I done wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your final code statement doesn't work is that it creates a whole new instance of a `WalkthroughViewController`.

Maybe the easiest way to handle this would be to have weak reference back to the view you want to change. *Make sure it's `weak`, otherwise you'll create a retain cycle and never be able to deallocate the view.* So:

Have a public property in `WalkthroughPageViewController`:

```
weak var buttonContainerView: UIView?
```

then in `WalkthroughViewController`'s `viewDidLoad()` (you'll need a reference to your sub-viewController but I can't see how that's set up... let's say you have something called `walkthroughPageViewController`):

```
walkthroughPageViewController.buttonContainerView = self.view
```

and somewhere inside `WalkthroughPageViewController`'s `contentViewController()`:

```
buttonContainerView?.backgroundColor = pageBackgroundColorArray[index]
```

Comment: That got it to work, however it does not stay synced with the index. So if I am on page 1 and the top is blue the bottom is the default color. Then if I swipe it will sync but if I swipe back it loses its 1:1 sync in the index